# What can cause an App not responding error for Buildfire plugins?

Tags: buildfire

I've been trying to diagnose this error happening on some user's devices - it is only happening on Android devices and only for a fraction of Android users, and, apparently only for a specific plugin I've developed. It started early March after I made some updates to the plugin code. Where and when the error is occurring, however, is unrelated to the code that I updated. Furthermore, I've never encountered this error for bugs related to the plugin's code so am perplexed / want to verify that it is something related to the plugin's code rather than something bigger. Normally, errors caused by bugs would just result in the plugin not responding or doing what would normally be the expected behavior, whereas this is a Buildfire error message, so I was hoping I could get some insight as to what could lead to this.

[image]

Comment: This doesnt seem like the native dialog on BuildFire. Are there any console logs you can share?

Comment: I looked further into this and this message comes up when the app is stuck/hung. I'd check your plugin code to see if you have any loops. If so, the first place I'd check is to see if there is an infinite loop occurring.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel_Madain . I set up Airbrake to catch any errors and wrapped all loops in try/catch statements. I haven't seen any relevant nor significant (in terms of volume) errors reported. For further context, we've found that the issue is only occurring on the paid version of the plugin and certain Android devices. The related code hasn't change within the plugin, so at this point I'm kind of stumped as to what the root cause could be. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Which Plugin are you using and do you have steps to reproduce?

Comment: It is the CookBook [b99b546b-5fd7-4b34-a79f-568d3105957d] plugin... Reproducing has been my issue. I issued a survey to the ~40 people experiencing the issue. What I've gathered is that all are Android users on paid versions of the plugin, and the point at which the error occurs varies but is typically very shortly after opening the plugin - sometimes without interacting with the plugin, others after clicking something. 

As I mentioned in my last message, Airbrake isn't catching the error, so I'm perplexed to the potential cause.

Comment: This seems to be done by a third-party developer R. Osborn. The support email should be listed in the marketplace. I'd suggest contacting them directly since the code is private and not public.